# Custom UI elements with cocoa touch

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iOS development and I'm still taking my time through the documentation and other literature. I would like to create my own custom UI elements for an app and I'm having an hard time finding out how.

Specifically, I would like to create:

1) A table view with custom row elements. I would like to add a picture, a title, a subtitle, and so on.

2) A custom navigation bar, which I can swipe to the sides, changing the bar itself as well as some content.

I would like these controls to have a custom design (that is, content, color, background, etc). How can I do this? Are there any good tutorials out there?

Regards.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your second specification?

Comment: I want to be able to swipe the top bar on the screen. This way, instead of using it for navigation, I would use it for something else, like changing the context in which the app is running (say switching from "editable content" to "static content").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed do that:

**1) A table view with custom row elements. I would like to add a picture, a title, a subtitle, and so on.**

You can customize your UITableView using custom cell concept.

The below tutorial is a great one and easy to follow.

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

**2) A custom navigation bar, which I can swipe to the sides, changing the bar itself as well as some content.**

You can edit the color, background and add a titleView to your UINavigationBar. Another great tutorial on this below:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

I'm not sure why you want to add swipe to your navigation bar but if you still would like to, you may wnat to try adding swipe gestures to that and see if that suits your requirements.

Comment: I'm not using the top area for navigation (or, at least, I want to try it out). Instead, the idea is to take advantage of that space for something else, just not sure what yet. I'm just experimenting ;) thank you for your reply! I'll hold accepting your answer to give some time for others.